# Conditionals against variables

Tags: linux, ansible, vmware

I am building a snapshot management playbook and that checks for an existing snap before taking a snap. I am having trouble testing a conditional when the playbook finds an existing snap. Here is a sample code:

```
---
- name: Test Snapshot
  hosts: axwayT
  gather_facts: false
  
  vars_files:
    - vault/creds.yml

  vars:
    mail_body_file: "/tmp/ansible_mail"

  pre_tasks:

    - name: Delete mail body file
      file:
        state: absent
        path: "{{ mail_body_file }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - name: Create mail body file
      file:
        state: touch
        path: "{{ mail_body_file }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
    
  tasks:
    
    - name: find guest's folder using name
      vmware_guest_find:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: no
        name: "{{ vcenter_hostgroup_name }}"
        datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
      register: vm_folder
      delegate_to: localhost
    
    - name: Check for existing snapshots
      vmware_guest:
         hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
         username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
         password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
         validate_certs: no
         name: "{{ vcenter_hostgroup_name }}"
         datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
         folder: "{{vm_folder.folders[0]}}"
         name: "{{ vcenter_hostgroup_name }}"
         state: present
      register: vm_state
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: debug
      debug:
        var: vm_state.instance.current_snapshot

    - name: Test
      shell: echo "Found!"
      when: vm_state.instance.current_snapshot !=""
```

I am working with an inventory of two servers for testing, nothing special. Here is the ouput I want to use a conditional against:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [swipe901.test.com] => {
    "vm_state.instance.current_snapshot": ""
}
ok: [swipe902.test.com] => {
    "vm_state.instance.current_snapshot": {
        "creation_time": "2023-02-07T21:14:06.812901+00:00",
        "description": "",
        "id": 13,
        "name": "VM Snapshot 2%2f7%2f2023, 3:14:05 PM",
        "state": "poweredOn"
    }
}
```

I tried two when statements:

```
when: vm_state.instance.current_snapshot =""
when: vm_state.instance.current_snapshot is defined
```

My logic is way off and I am seeing my own limitations with programing logic, which I plan to fix soon.

My plan for the logic is to, skip a step, in my playbook if vm_state.instance.current_snapshot is "". How would this be handled?

Comment: The conditional almost works. FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'vm_state.instance.current_snapshot|d('default')|length == 0' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if vm_state.instance.current_snapshot|d('default')|length == 0 %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): object of type 'NoneType' has no len()\n\n

Comment: Hey! By setting this the conditional, the state thats populated in current_snapshot, will also evaluate as true. I would like the condition to evaulate false if there is anything populated in current_snapshot. I am thinking of taking vm_state.instance.current_snapshot.state is not defined.

Comment: When I set, vm_state.instance.current_snapshot.state is not defined. I get the result I want. It skips the server that does not have a state defined, since no existing snapshot exist. I am probably doing this backwards, with my weak logic understanding, but it works.

Comment: I added an answer and removed the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"I would like the condition to evaluate `false` if there is anything populated in current_snapshot."***

A: For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- name: Evaluate false if there is anything populated in current_snapshot
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: The variable current_snapshot is either empty or does not exist.
      when: current_snapshot|d('', true)|length == 0
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [Evaluate false if there is anything populated in current_snapshot] *************************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: The variable current_snapshot is either empty or does not exist.

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e current_snapshot=''

PLAY [Evaluate false if there is anything populated in current_snapshot] *************************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: The variable current_snapshot is either empty or does not exist.

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e current_snapshot='anything'

PLAY [Evaluate false if there is anything populated in current_snapshot] *************************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

You can also use *assert*. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- name: Evaluate false if there is anything populated in current_snapshot
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that: current_snapshot|d('', true)|length == 0
        success_msg: The variable current_snapshot is either empty or does not exist.
        fail_msg: The variable current_snapshot is populated.
```

Comment: Amazing! Here is what happened when I tested: current_snapshot|d('', true)|length == 0 - I added 'default' so my code was current_snapshot|d('default', true)|length == 0. That you shared works perfectly. May I ask what resources have you encountered to learn this? There is minimum documentation about handling conditionals in Ansible. From my searches.

Comment: Here you only need to understand how [*default*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values) works. Generally, read https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/. For example, [*Manipulating data*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html#manipulating-data) is useful.